# how to download .csv file from android webview without getting proper URL

Tags: java, android, webview

I developed a web application in spring framework. Downloading is working fine in the web application, but for webview, the file is not downloading. I used Android's onDownloadStart() from DownloadListener, but onDownloadStart() is not working properly(may be he is not receiving proper URL). I am getting the path of the file to be downloaded(not exact URL).So thats why he doesn't worked.

here is my download code

webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

```
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)
            {
                //for downloading directly through download manager
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside download",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does the DownloadListener get called?

Comment: yeah it is getting called in normal webpage screen but not getting called in magnify popup screen. do you have any idea!!!!!!!